# Google Plus New Login confusing over old method?

Tags: google-plus

I currently have a big problem with using the new Google Plus login API.
Before I connected a user and was able to get via php the users details if they are logged in and authenticated. If not they clicked the connect me button and it logged in. (This is from the sample plus application in the php api.

How would I approach the new API to be able to login? I tried the server side guide but it seems to me incomplete and I assume I can't use the client side when its being used for a php login.

Is there another persons guide or someone who knows how to follow the server side api and could tell me how to do this type of thing?

Thanks - Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1) use the Google+ Sign-In button and the one-time code flow

Use the javascript button to start the sign-in. When the user signs in, along with the access token, the client receives an auth code that you can send to your backend. The backend can then exchange the code for an access token and a refresh token. 
The [PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php) shows you this type of flow. This is the recommended option.

2) use the OAuth 2.0 flow for web server applications

Documented [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) and used in the sample shipped with the PHP Client Library. All you need to do is use the 'plus.login' scope. If you use a custom button, be sure to comply with the [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines). [Over-the-air installs](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs) are not available when you use this flow.